# How to allow the shutdown of computer using web server?

Tags: server, bash, apache2, shutdown, php

I have a web server under apache2 and php5. I want to shutdown a computer using web server but to shutdown the computer a current user should be 'root' user because command for the turning off of PC 'shuwdown -h now' should be executed under root user. 
The php user is called 'www-data'.

I have such files

## file: shutdown.sh

`#!/bin/bash`
`echo $(shutdown -h now);`

## file: shutdown.php

If this script will be called the script 'shutdown.sh' should be executed.
`<?php`
`echo "Shutdown";`
`echo exec ( 'shutdown.sh' );`
`?>`

The question:how to execute file 'shutdown.sh'  as root user without password.
Or maybe are another ways exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give www-data permission to execute the shutdown command. Try this:

As root, use the command 'visudo' to edit your /etc/sudoers file. The last lines should look like this:

> # Cmnd alias specification
>
> # User privilege specification
>
> root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
>
> # Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
>
> %admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

So, in the end of the file, insert:

> www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown

Then exit the editor and save it (CTRL+x).

The user www-data should be able to call shutdown now, without sudo password.

Comment: Thanks for answer but it didn't help me. I added a line to file /etc/sudoerc artem ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown, artem is my account, then I tried to execute command in terminal '/sbin/shutdown -h now' and it requires password from me.

Comment: Oh, you need to call it like 'sudo /sbin/shutdown ...', sudo is still needed, but it will see that you are authorized to do that without a password. Also, remember to restart sudo service 'service sudo restart' before that.

Comment: Thanks, you have helped me a lot. The command 'sudo' has to be called before a script.